# Cannot connect to already running ide instance. exception: process 2 is still running on linux mint

Tags: linux, exception, intellij-idea

The "Cannot connect to already running IDE instance" error typically occurs when IntelliJ IDEA detects that another instance of the IDE is already running and prevents you from starting a new one. To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

First, try closing the existing instance of IntelliJ IDEA. If you are encountering this error when trying to start the IDE, you can skip this step.

Open a terminal and use the following commands to remove the "lock" file:

`cd ~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate/config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2`

`rm -r .lock`

The above commands navigate to the directory where IntelliJ IDEA is installed and deletes the "lock" file. If you are not using the "Ultimate" version or your installation path is different, make sure to adjust the commands accordingly.

Now, try restarting IntelliJ IDEA. The error should be resolved, and the IDE should start without any issues.

These steps are designed to remove the "lock" file used by a running instance of IntelliJ IDEA, allowing you to start a new instance. Please note that these instructions are specific to JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version. If you are using a different version, the directory path and file name may vary, so you should check the directory where IntelliJ IDEA is installed to determine the correct path and file name to remove.

My problem is that I encountered the 'Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. exception: process 2 is still running' error, and as a result, I can't open the application.

Comment: you can adapt the solution for PhpStorm as well. Here are the steps to resolve the "Cannot connect to already running IDE instance" error for PhpStorm:                                                       `cd ~/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PhpStorm/config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2023.2`                                     `rm -r .lock` Now, try restarting PhpStorm. The error should be resolved, and PhpStorm should start without any issues.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command `kill -9 [pid]` or remove **.lock** file in your **Home/.config/JetBrains/idedir/**

Comment: On macOS you can use the `top` command to see the top running programs and their PID's. Or you can use a command like this to get the right PID based on app name (this is looking for Android Studio): `ps -Ac | grep studio | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux simply type:

sudo kill -9 process_id

example:
sudo kill -9 2915

Hope it helps.