# Android Studio - IDE Already Running error when launched

Tags: android-studio, cordova

I have been installing the needed components to build Android apps with Cordova on my Mac (OS 13.4.1).  I am now at a point where the results of my cordova requirements query is:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.21

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: not installed 

Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/8.5/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for browser:
Some of requirements check failed


I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, killing processes, and a few other methods I've found online, but my Android Studio install seems to be missing something?  Not only am I getting this error above, but when I attempt to open the Android Studio I have installed, I receive this IDE Already Running error:

Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.
CannotActivateException: /Users/tomadkins/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1

The directory above (/Users/tomadkins/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1) does not exist on my machine.
```

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, killing processes, and a few other methods I've found online.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the owner of `~/Library/Application Support/Google` was `root`.

try `sudo chown tomadkins ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google`

Answer (score 0):

```
Android target: not installed
```

You do not have the target Android SDK installed. Go to your Android Studio app then install the appropriate SDK

Comment: As stated, I try to open the Android Studio to try and get to the SDK Manager, but I receive the "Cannot connect to already running IDE instance." error on launch.  I've tried to go through and kill any processes associated with android, but the error remains.

Comment: Maybse see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213683/cannot-connect-to-already-running-ide-instance-exception-process-2-is-still-ru

Comment: Over the weekend, I was able to do the suggestions and get the Android Studio to open.  I added the top two versions of available SDKs, however the "Android target: not installed" message when I check the requirements.  Could this be an environment variable issue or mismatch?  export PATH="/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools:${PATH}"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home